Magento 2 Not able to update customer field taxvat
Magento 2.4.7
The customer field "taxvat" (NOT customer address field "vat_id") can't be updated if it's not used on creation of the customer. On creation, if a value is there, it will be stored into table Customer Entity Varchar. If it's not, the record won't be created and therefor can not be updated. Any solutions besides creating the record manually?

Are you getting errors on the admin or frontend side? also, the check value of taxvat is passed in request.

On Creating New Account, if there is not data for taxvat, then pass an empty value,So taxvat field may be saved in Customer Entity Varchar and on update field will be available.

Actually it turned out the taxtvat field was altered, perhaps by some extension, perhaps by change in magento.
In the eav_attribute table backend type was set to varchar, should have been static and attribute_model was Magento\Customer\Model|Attrubte and should have been Null. After changing that to the default magento  values all workes fine.
